# After recently starting to earn a salary, when do I need to pay zakat?

Tags: ramadan, zakat, nisab

I have few doubts in mind regarding Zakat.

1) I have started earning Salary since February 2017 and it's Ramadan now, so I need to know when do I need to pay Zakat for the salary which is getting accumulated since February 2017?

2) Also I would like to know that Zakat is paid on wealth above nisab. So is the Zakat paid on the wealth which is only above nisab or the whole wealth including Nisab?

Comment: I encourage you to split this question into two separate questions; there's problems with asking [multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2965/17163).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not only the salary that will be counted. Your property(Includes all the property you have [Details Here](https://www.al-islam.org/a-summary-of-rulings-makarim-shirazi/rules-zakah)) has to be reached the amount of a Nisaab and stay with you for 1 lunar year. As soon as this criteria is fulfilled pick a date and calculate all the property you have and give Zakat.
   Remember, only the Nisaab amount need to be stay with you for one year. If you have Nisaab amount on the the beginning of the year and on the end of the year you must give Zakat on that year and calculate all the property you have on that time even though you had nothing in the middle of the year.
   N.B. If your salary is the only property you have and its above Nisaab then you need to calculate your Zakat next year February.
2. Whole wealth including Nisab.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i do not have any property or gold on my name. the salary accumulated is above Nisab as of now but it has only been 5 months it is with me. So this means i have to give zakat next February as 1 year will be completed on my Salary?

Comment: Yes, inshallah at the end of 1 lunar year it is due on you if save above the nisaab after all your expenditures. But I also advise you to give some sadaqa during this Ramadan of 2017 so that you may receive baraka, more sawaab and inshallah raise your status in jannah. It can be even a single dollar but inshallah the reward is great :) Salaam!